# Can't login via SSH once host has been up for 36 hours

Tags: linux, ssh

I have a really weird issue trying to login into a local linux box. Once the host has been up for about 36+ hours I can't login via ssh at all.

If I restart the host then I'm able to login via SSH no problems.

I've checked the host logs and can't see anything immediatley that could hint at the cause of the issue.

The remote host is on the same network as the client I'm trying to login from. And the host is running Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.4.112-sun7i armv7l).

When running a ssh with extra verbosity, at a point after 36+ hours up time, I get the following output.

```
OpenSSH_7.5p1, LibreSSL 2.5.4
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/enwhat/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/enwhat/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 52: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "192.168.0.20" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.20 [192.168.0.20] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/enwhat/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/enwhat/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/enwhat/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/enwhat/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/enwhat/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/enwhat/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/enwhat/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/enwhat/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.5
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: Have you inspected the system log entries between success and failure?

Comment: I've used `tail` on both /var/log/auth.log and /var/log/syslog whilst trying to run an ssh login command and I don't see any log entries that hint at any issues to do with SSH.

Comment: That's because it wouldn't be a SSH problem. It would be a system problem that happened *between* those times.

Comment: I'm able to login to the host in question, via another SSH / Linux box else where on my local network. When I login via this secondary SSH login, I see an entry appear in /var/log/auth.log `Nov 10 23:14:52 homeassistant systemd-logind[551]: New session c11 of user`. However I see no entries when logging in via the client that's having the connection / login issue. Can you suggest anything else to look out for or any specific log files?

Comment: Is the clock correct on the new host?

Comment: That could be an issue. The host is a BananaPi. It’s possible the clock was getting out of sync. So I’ve setup regular ntp clock syncing. Hopefully this might resolve the issue...

Comment: This issue still seems to be persisting. After uptime of about 36+ hours I just can't login via SSH from specific local hosts. Is there anything else it could be?